# React how to display ErrorMessage in Input Form

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using react and antd.
I'm using antd's Input component.
I want to display an Error message at the bottom of the Input form if more than 10 characters are entered.
I want to use antd's errorMessage.

[code](https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tree-xe4xm?file=/src/App.js:0-775)

```
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [onSave, setOnSave] = React.useState(null);
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setValue(Number(e.target.value));
  }, []);

  const onSaveBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (String(value).length < 10) {
      setOnSave(true);
    } else {
      setOnSave(false);
    }
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={onSaveBlur}
      ></Input>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out this:

```
  import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { Input, Form } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [onSave, setOnSave] = React.useState(null);
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
  }, []);

  const onSaveBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (String(value).length < 10) {
      setOnSave(true);
    } else {
      setOnSave(false);
    }
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Form>
        <Form.Item
          label="Number"
          name="number"
          rules={[
            { required: true, message: "Please input value!" },
            { max: 10, message: "length should be less then 10 letters!" }
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            type="number"
            value={value}
            onChange={handleInputChange}
            onBlur={onSaveBlur}
          ></Input>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit beautiful-danny-f0pc2]

Comment: I used antd's errorMessage.　https://ant.design/components/form/

Comment: @aahhuhuhu Edited. Please check it again.

Comment: What is the role of name="username"?
When I remove name="username", the error message is no longer displayed.

Comment: @aahhuhuhu Nothing, It's just a name and label for the input.

Answer (score 1):

You can add Default AntD rule inside Form.Item like below

```
<Form.Item
   rules = {[{  max:10, message: "length should be less then 10 
   letters!"}]}
>
   <Input placeholder="Username"/>
 </Form.Item>
```

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tree-xe4xm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: I copied the above code and used it, but I get an error.

Comment: @aahhuhuhu <InputNumber min={1} max={10} value={value} onChange={setValue} />
you can even use InputNumber component of antd it's super simple for your example
Refer this: https://ant.design/components/input-number/

Comment: I've fixed it, but I'm still getting errors.　　https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tree-xe4xm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Check this codesandbox i have edited
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-tree-xe4xm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @aahhuhuhu here i have added updated codesandbox please check
https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-silence-iytsz

Comment: @aahhuhuhu replace rules: to rules=. The issue is with colon after rules attribute

Comment: @aahhuhuhu refer below link
https://codesandbox.io/s/q-60606351-formapi-forked-0ble9?file=/index.js:575-626

Comment: I'm getting an error message after typing two characters, and I want to get an error message after typing 10 characters or more.

Comment: I applied max={10} to Input, but it allows me to enter more than 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an error state and display it following the condition:

```js
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "antd";

const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(null);
  const [onSave, setOnSave] = React.useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = React.useState(null)
  
  const handleInputChange = React.useCallback((e) => {
    setValue(Number(e.target.value));
  }, []);

  const onSaveBlur = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (String(value).length < 10) {
      setOnSave(true);
    } else {
      setError(isLowerCase ? null : 'error message')
      setOnSave(false);
    }
  }, [value]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Input
        type="number"
        value={value}
        onChange={handleInputChange}
        onBlur={onSaveBlur}
      ></Input>
      <div role="alert" style={{color: 'red'}}>
        {error}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I would like to use errorMessage from the antd library.　　https://ant.design/components/form/